# How to wrap a div around the logo in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, design

I am trying to wrap a div around the logo image in Magento 2. I have tried the below but no luck. Thanks for any help!

> ```
>     <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
>         <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="logo.wrapper" after="-">
>             <arguments>
>                 <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">logo.wrapper</argument>
>             </arguments>
>         </block>
>     </referenceContainer>
> ```

Comment: did you get the solution for this ? if not then let me know , its simple phtml file edit

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code may help you

**Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="logo.wrapper" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">logo.wrapper</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work either :-(

Answer (score 2):

In `vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                            <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

You can see that the logo block is under the header-wrapper, so what you can do is create a container insider the header-wrapper then move the logo into your container.

In your theme `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <container name="new.logo.wrapper" label="New Logo Wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="new-logo-wrapper"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="logo" destination="new.header.wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

=> Then the logo will be moved to the new wrapper. **Clean the cache if it's enabled.**

Comment: I think currently, the `move` element should have an `element` attribute, rather than a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below xml code to wrap the logo in div:-

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="container.name" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="classname">    
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="logo.wrapper" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">logo.wrapper</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>    
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope this help you.